# Fastest way to modify one digit of an integer

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, number-theory

Suppose I have an `int x = 54897`, old digit index (0 based), and the new value for that digit. What's the fastest way to get the new value?

Example

```
x = 54897
index = 3
value = 2
y = f(x, index, value) // => 54827
```

Edit: by fastest, I definitely mean faster performance. No string processing.

Comment: So, your index counts from left to right (most significant to least significant?)

Comment: I take it we can assume base 10?

Comment: Well, converting to a string, swapping the digit, and converting back to an integer is the fastest way I know to *code* that, but something tells me that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: The fastest in terms of development time would be to convert it to a string, replace the digit using an index into the string, and convert it back to a number.

Comment: LarsH: yes base10, and I'm looking for faster in terms of performance, not the time to write the code.

Comment: @Adam: what tests led you to determine that the performance of string processing would be unsatisfactory in this case? I ask because, most likely, the next developer to run across whatever solution you come up with could be mighty unhappy with you. This is fine for personal edification, but don't put this in software without a really good reason.

Comment: this is __not__ language agnostic. The solution will depend on if it's interpreted (and then how), if it runs on a VM (which one) and if it's compiled (which architecture). It probably depends on all of them to some extend.

Comment: +1 Michael - doing `f()` in a string is trivial (and fast). The question is then how fast you can convert a string to and from an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simplest case (considering the digits are numbered from LSB to MSB, the first one being 0) AND knowing the old digit, we could do as simple as that:

```
num += (new_digit - old_digit) * 10**pos;
```

For the real problem we would need:

1) the MSB-first version of the `pos`, that could cost you a `log()` or at most `log10(MAX_INT)` divisions by ten (could be improved using binary search).

2) the digit from that `pos` that would need at most 2 divisions (or zero, using results from step 1).

You could also use the special fpu instruction from x86 that is able to save a float in BCD (I have no idea how slow it is).

UPDATE: the first step could be done even faster, without any divisions, with a binary search like this:

```
int my_log10(unsigned short n){
    // short: 0.. 64k -> 1.. 5 digits 
    if (n < 1000){  // 1..3
        if (n <  10) return 1;
        if (n < 100) return 2;
        return 3;
    } else { // 4..5
        if (n < 10000) return 4;
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your index started at the least significant digit, you could do something like

```
p = pow(10,index);
x = (x / (p*10) * (p*10) + value * p + x % p).
```

But since your index is backwards, a string is probably the way to go. It would also be more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Er... The final expression is incorrect. Should probably be `x / (p*10) * (p*10) + ...` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the "mask" `M`: 10 raised to the power of `index`, where `index` is a zero-based index from the right. If you need to index from the left, recalculate `index` accordingly.
2. Calculate the "prefix" `PRE = x / (M * 10) * (M * 10)`
3. Calculate the "suffix" `SUF = x % M`
4. Calculate the new "middle part" `MID = value * M`
5. Generate the new number `new_x = PRE + MID + POST`.

P.S. ruslik's answer does it more elegantly :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by figuring out how many digits are in your input. I can think of two ways of doing that, one with a loop and one with logarithms. Here's the loop version. This will fail for negative and zero inputs and when the index is out of bounds, probably other conditions too, but it's a starting point.

```
def f(x, index, value):
    place = 1
    residual = x
    while residual > 0:
        if index < 0:
            place *= 10
        index -= 1
        residual /= 10
    digit = (x / place) % 10
    return x - (place * digit) + (place * value)
```

P.S. This is working Python code. The principle of something simple like this is easy to work out, but the details are so tricky that you really need to iterate it a bit. In this case I started with the principle that I wanted to subtract out the old digit and add the new one; from there it was a matter of getting the correct multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta get specific with your compute platform if you're talking about performance.

I would approach this by converting the number into pairs of decimal digits, 4 bit each.

Then I would find and process the pair that needs modification as a byte.

Then I would put the number back together.

There are assemblers that do this very well.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: In all fairness, whatever I may come up with using Fortran 90, there will be a clever guy with a PowerPC assembler that does it faster.